# Save image area and load

Tags: c#, php, .net, vb.net

I need to load a picture and save some areas into a database (like you do it on Facebook when tag peopple into pictures).

I need to save de selected area and then, in another form, show the picture and the selected areas in blue

I have to do it with vb .net or php

does someone have any example or clue?

thank  you in advance

Comment: Write some code to show the image with a 'rectangle' select tool. Forward the x/y coordinates to the server and let the server chop the image into the correct size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a plugin for jquery called imagecrop
this is a (old!) component which you could adept:
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/klagoggle_myopenid_com/2010/08/25/jquery-image-upload-crop

Answer (score 0):

PHP has several image-manipulation functions if compiled with the GD extension. You can copy a portion of an image to another (create new), or use the [`imagerectangle()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerectangle.php) function to draw blue rectangles over the tagged areas.

Comment: thank you for your answer..I´m checking it if I would be abble to set an rectangle with the mouse and store it somehow

Comment: The actual capturing of the user mouse click in relation to the image would have to be done with Javascript. Once captured, an AJAX call could tell the PHP script to draw a square/rectangle at that location, or Javascript could update the DOM to put a blue rectangle image over the base image (`z-Index` and `position:absolute` manipulation).

Comment: see this jQuery plugin: [ImgNotes](http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2009/01/23/img-notes-v02-a-couple-of-bug-fixes-and-some-more/)